# Rails 3: Inner join with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join

I'm a bit stuck on an Active Record query problem. I'd like to do a left join instead of an inner join on a query, but the results of the `joins` method are returning only an inner join.

```
Entry.
  joins(:measurements => :measurement_type).
  sum(:value, :conditions => ['name = ?','Calories'])
```

The tricky part is that `:measurements` has a belongs_to relationship to `:measurement_type` which is where the name column resides.

Right now this is returning sums only for users who have food_posts. The goal is to return sums for all users. Users who don't have a food post would have a sum of zero.

I've tried Googling and searching other posts on here, but haven't found an answer. Any suggestions?

Also I'm using SQLite in my development environment and Postgresql for production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do a left join instead of an inner join you need to use custom 'sql fragments'

In your example,

```
relation.joins("left join measurements on measurements.id = measurement_type.measurements_id")
```

Or something along those lines dependent on your setup.

This [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) sums it up pretty clearly.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I had do a longer query than your example for the additional association, which is what I was stuck on. Which it could be more succinct, but here's what I ended up with: `relation.joins("LEFT JOIN measurements ON measurements.entry_id = entries.id").joins("INNER JOIN measurement_types ON measurement_types.id = measurements.measurement_type_id")`

Comment: I suspected as much. I wasn't 100% clear on your DB schema from your original post. P.S. If a question solves your problem don't forget to accept :)

Answer (score 1):

MetaWhere gem has support for outer joins, among much other goodness:

https://github.com/ernie/meta_where

Comment: For Rails 3.1 and above, replaced by [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel).  Ryan Bates has [a Railscast about it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/354-squeel).